# Combine data for each id in to one row and remove duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

I need help with my LINQ query.
I have an table where I have such data structure:

```
Employee ID|Action|Manager     |HR BP  |Location     |EffectiveDate|
000001     |UPDATE|John        |Martha |Berlin       |2020-04-10   |
000003     |UPDATE|Fillip      |""     |London       |2020-04-10   |
000002     |UPDATE|Thomas      |Julia  |Madrit       |2020-04-10   |
000001     |UPDATE|John        |""     |""           |2020-04-10   |
000003     |UPDATE|""          |""     |London       |2020-04-10   |
000002     |UPDATE|""          |""     |Madrit       |2020-04-10   |
```

I need to combine data for each employee in to one row and remove duplicates:

```
Employee ID|Action|Manager     |HR BP  |Location     |EffectiveDate|
000001     |UPDATE|John        |Martha |Berlin       |2020-04-10   |
000003     |UPDATE|Fillip      |""     |London       |2020-04-10   |
000002     |UPDATE|Thomas      |Julia  |Madrit       |2020-04-10   |
```

On the internet I found such linq query but it doesn't give me the answer:

```
string ErrorMessage = "";
DataTable CollectionOut = new DataTable();
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
try
{
    dt1 = CollectionIn;

    DataTable dtMerged = dt1.AsEnumerable()
                        .GroupBy(r => new {d= r.Field<string>("Employee ID"), f=r.Field<string>("EffectiveDate") })
                        .Select(g => g.First()).CopyToDataTable();
    CollectionOut = dtMerged;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ErrorMessage = ex.Message.ToString();

}
```

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Have you sure the data always could be combination without conflict? I mean these would be 2 rows same id with 2 `Manager` difference names like "John" and "John2". So what rule that you want to keep one?

Comment: Yes, because the table is only a combination of few other tables in to one and that's why there are such duplicates.

Comment: _but it doesn't give me the answer_ - can you describe what is wrong with given answer?

Comment: @Mirosław Gądek I posted my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept here is we're going to group by them with desired `group.count` always be 2.
Then we merge with using the first row and loop all the columns. If the column is empty, then use the respective value from the second rows.

Assuming that I have the data row like

[image]

```
        mTest.Columns.Add("Employee ID");
        mTest.Columns.Add("Action");
        mTest.Columns.Add("Manager");
        mTest.Columns.Add("HR BP");
        mTest.Columns.Add("Location");
        mTest.Columns.Add("EffectiveDate");

        mTest.Rows.Add("000001", "UPDATE", "", "Martha", "", "2020-04-10");
        mTest.Rows.Add("000003", "UPDATE", "Fillip", "", "London", "2020-04-10");
        mTest.Rows.Add("000002", "UPDATE", "Thomas", "", "Madrit", "2020-04-10");
        mTest.Rows.Add("000002", "UPDATE", "Thomas", "Julia", "Madrit", "2020-04-10");
        mTest.Rows.Add("000001", "UPDATE", "John", "", "Berlin", "2020-04-10");
        mTest.Rows.Add("000003", "UPDATE", "Fillip", "", "London", "2020-04-10");
        mTest.Rows.Add("000003", "UPDATE", "", "", "London", "2020-04-10");
        mTest.Rows.Add("000002", "UPDATE", "", "Julia", "", "2020-04-10");

        dataGridView.DataSource = mTest;
```

Then I implement the combination function

```
    private DataTable Combination(DataTable dt)
    {
        List<DataRow> rows = new List<DataRow>();

        foreach (var group in dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("Employee ID")).Select(x => x.ToList()))
        {
            if (group.Count() == 1)
            {
                rows.Add(group[0]);
                continue;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < group[0].ItemArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(group[0][i].ToString()))
                    group[0][i] = group[1][i];
            }

            rows.Add(group[0]);
        }

        // Using DataTableExtensions
        return rows.CopyToDataTable();
    }
```

And the result

```
dataGridView.DataSource = Combination(mTest);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you. Now Im gettin an error: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Maybe it is an issue of the example table. My true table is bigger has more then 6 columns.

Comment: @Miroslaw May be these have no duplication after group by. I updated my answer